# Kill command also kills other process

Tags: shell, scripting, process, kill

I have a very simple script, let's call it foo.sh. It's this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sxhkd &
panel &
```

where `panel` is a script (I won't post it here because it's very long and I don't think it would be relevant) which will spawn some child processes.
I execute the script with `sh foo.sh`.
Now, my problem is that if I kill panel from another shell with `pkill panel` for some reason sxhkd is also killed, and that is very undesiderable. I tried ampersand, disown, nohup, and I haven't got other ideas.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

untested, but try

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup sxhkd </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
nohup panel </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

To completely disassociate them from each other

Comment: Tried now, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check that panel doesn't have any  traps that might kill the other process

Comment: Oh, damn. thank you, that was it! Panel had a trap I didn't notice.

Comment: What did the trap look like? I have the exact same problem running panel and sxhkd. (I copied somebody's panel a long while back and modified it heavily)